# How do I print the query that Python uses to call the database?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How do I print to the terminal the query used by a specific line of python code? see below

```
notifications = user.get_notifications(max_id=max_id, types=types).order_by('-created')[:count]
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. [Please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to look for existing answers before asking - finding the linked duplicate was as easy as putting `[django] print query` into the site search - and please do not make "thanks" comments - instead, see the advice at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the query by adding:

```
.query
```

after your call.

It'll look like this:

```
user.get_notifications(max_id=max_id, types=types).order_by('-created')[:count].query
```

If you're doing this in the `py manage.py shell`, don't forget to `print()` it out. Otherwise it will show a memory address.